# How to bind to data-* attribute in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-dart

Assuming I have really large grid of cells I want to add data-row and data-col atribute values and bind from model. How can I bind data-row from angular2 (beta0 in Dart).

Binding with data-row="{{boundVal}}" does not seem to work.
(no data attribute appears in output html)

eg.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="#row of rows" >
      <td *ngFor="#cell of row.cells" data-row="{{row.index}}" data-col="{{cell.index}}" >
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good question :-)

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
[attr.data-row]="row.index" [attr.data-col]="cell.index"
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How can I pass this data-row value in click event?

Comment: just pass `cell.index`