# Angular - Can't bind to 'property' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: angular, twitter, bind

I have my two object

```
{
  "twitter": {
    "username": "potus",
    "postslimit": 10
  },
  "enum": [],
  "publicationdate": "2018-08-27T15:05:55.410Z",
  "_id": "5b8414ec3412b43a34f050cf",
  "clicks": [],
  "active": true,
  "user": " __ ",
  "type": "twitter",
  "__v": 0
}
```

If I dislay:

```
<a 
  class="twitter-timeline" 
  data-tweet-limit="2" 
  href="https://twitter.com/{{tw.twitter.username}}">
</a>
```

everything works fine, but when I'm trying to bind the `data-tweet-limit` like this:

```
<a 
  class="twitter-timeline" 
  data-tweet-limit="{{tw.twitter.postslimit}}"
  href="https://twitter.com/{{tw.twitter.username}}">
</a>
```

I get:

> Can't bind to 'tweet-limit' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("'">
>                         
>                         ]data-tweet-limit="{{tw.twitter.postslimit}}"   href="https://twitter.com/{{tw.twitter.username}}">

(I'm loading the twitter timeline like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40572479/4350966))

Comment: Are you sure the `data-tweet-limit` is an attribute on the anchor tag? I'm not able to see it here: https://publish.twitter.com/?query=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FTwitterDev%2Ftimelines%2F539487832448843776&widget=Grid

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera thank you for replying , and yes, for example in the link you sent if you click "set customization options" you can see it, and also if I set it with a  static default like  data-tweet-limit="2" it works and prints only 2 tweets, I think the problem is that Angular doesent want to bind this attribute because it's not a default anchor attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to data-\* attribute in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412103/how-to-bind-to-data-attribute-in-angular2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a post explaining how to use data attributes

[How to bind to data-* attribute in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412103/how-to-bind-to-data-attribute-in-angular2)

Basically, you should use the following

```
[attr.data-tweet-limit]="tw.twitter.postslimit"
```

Comment: Consider flagging the question the as Duplicate instead of answering the question to better comply with the Quality Standards of StackOverflow.