# Angular - add custom (data) attribute to <option> using ngFor

Tags: angular, angular7, angular2-formbuilder

I need to add custom data attribute to select options. I want it because on change I want to trigger action based on selected attribute (not value)

Here is the code I am using

```
<select (domChange)="onListUpdate($event)" formControlName="region" id="region" class="selectric form-control">
    <option code="" value="-1">{{ 'select_country' | translate }}</option>
    <option data-isocode="{{region.iso_code}}" value="{{region.id}}" *ngFor="let region of regions">{{region.name['en']}}</option>
</select>
```

It works when I give static value to data attribute for example, the following works without any problem (notice the data-isocode has static value)

```
<option data-isocode="abc" value="{{region.id}}" *ngFor="let region of regions">{{region.name['en']}}</option>
```

However, when I try to use the variable in data-isocode

```
<option data-isocode="{{region.iso_code}}" value="{{region.id}}" *ngFor="let region of regions">{{region.name['en']}}</option>
```

It throws me following error

```
Can't bind to 'isocode' since it isn't a known property of 'option'
```

How do I pass the data attribute (like in jQuery) with Angular and get the value using FormBuilder?

Comment: Can you try binding like `[attr.data-isocode]="region.iso_code"` this?

Comment: do this way : ``[attr.data-isocode]="region.iso_code"`` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to data-\* attribute in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412103/how-to-bind-to-data-attribute-in-angular2)

Comment: Working, thanks, how do I access the value in .ts file using FormBuilder?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar You can get it via a `@ViewChild` binding with the element. But I don't understand. If you are binding a variable/property like `region.iso_code` did it not come from the `.ts` in the first place?

Comment: Or perhaps, you are looking at something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582487/4050218

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS I am using `formControlName` for binding, and accessing the whole form values using `this.form.value`

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar `this.form.value` gives the "value" elements only. You have to override the `value` with your data attribute value onChange if you want to access it there. But it'll be a roundabout way of getting things done.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you, appreciate your help.

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS, would you mind posting your comment as answer? I will accept it.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind to the `data-` attributes like this:

```
[attr.data-isocode]="region.iso_code"
```

You can access the value through an event binding like:

```
getData(event){
  console.log(event.target.dataset.isocode);
}
```

Accessing it via `this.form.value` is not possible though since `this.form.value` gives the "value" elements only. You have to override the value with your data attribute value onChange if you want to access it there. But it'll be a roundabout way of getting things done.